# netrw freezes if vim subwindow includes "beefy" network drive

Tags: netrw

When one of my vim subwindows is opened to a network drive with many zip files, switching to that subwindows causes vim to hang for 10 seconds or so.  The Windows Task Manager shows sustained increased bandwidth usage during that time, so I assume that netrw is reading the list of files within each zip file.  I am in a very controlled computational setting, so upgrading is not easy.  Is there a quick vim source code patch that alleviates this delay?  I am currently on netrw v149, installed as part of Cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: Can't you temporarily copy the zip file to local machine? Do you need to modify the content of the zip file?

Comment: I need to peruse the many zip files in the folder, selectively descending into some of them by opening those zip files from netrw (using the "o" key).  It's not just one zip file.

Comment: Current work-around: Save netrw's text view of the folder's files into a text file "x.txt" and forgo the "live" view of the folder using netrw., Then use vim registers to capture the folder path and the specific file of interest (both available in "x.txt") and assemble the full path of the file as an argument to the :e command.  This is made feasible only by exploiting vim functional behaviour.

Comment: I see. How do you specify the network drive/path to the vim. AFAIK, netrw usually use URL, eg: `vim scp://hostname/path/to/file`, `vim ftp://hostname/path/to/file` .

Comment: The 3rd line of the netrw screen shows as (for example) `/i/the/folder/path`.  Here `/i` is the network drive.  This is using gvim as packaged in cygwin, where `/i` maps to `i:\\` , However, gvim for windows shows similarly, e.g., `i:\the\folder\path`.  (Sorry for the weird parsing of the back-apostrophes -- they're suppose to highlight text as code inline with normal text).